# How to display image in the public folder in laravel

Tags: laravel

I cannot display image in the public folder. the image is stored in storage/app/public/product_images/; I tried this:

```
<img class="img-fluid img" src="{{ URL::to('/') }}/product_images/16.png">
```

I also tried

```
<img class="img-fluid img img-size" src="{{ asset('/product_images/16.png') }}">
```

when I use the developer tools in the browser I see this for both methods:

```
<div>
    <img class="img-fluid img img-size" src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/product_images/16.png">
</div>
```

The image is not showing, just that tiny square thumbnail used by brwsers when they cannot find an image

I am using laravel 8

Comment: I ran php artisan storage:link and it said The links have been created. but the image is still not showing

Comment: <img class="img-fluid img img-size" src="{{ asset('storage/product_images/16.png') }}">

Comment: I tried <img class="img-fluid img img-size" src="{{ asset('storage/product_images/16.png') }}"> and its working now. thank you all